# How to decode the return value of random_bytes() in PHP

Tags: php, encryption

I'm using `random_bytes()` to create a nonce which will return something like

```
��;w ���%N�:0���c1x*#�M��
```

Then when I `base64_decode()` it'll return something like `���` which is confusing because it's just a shorter version of something encrypted.
How do I get the actual string?

Comment: Those are multi-byte characters that have their encoding broken. In other words, you need to fix your charset/encoding issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong function :[`base64_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) is made to *decode* a base64 encoded string. Here your string is not base64 encoded so having a shorter string is totally normal.

To generate a random (readable) string you could either use [`bin2hex`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) or [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php):

```
$data = random_bytes(32);
$b = base64_encode($data);
echo $b;
xROAVp/JUq4DuEGe87HYINXncOHArYzc9oeziO/TTNw=
```

Answer (score 1):

Use bin2hex php function on the result so you can see it

```
bin2hex(random_bytes(number of bytes)) or 
base64_encode(bin2hex(random_bytes(number of bytes)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`random_bytes` doesn't return a base64-encoded value, so trying to decode one from the result won't get you very far.

[As the manual suggests](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php), if you're looking to generate a random "string", you need to run it through something like `bin2hex`:

```
$bytes = random_bytes(5);
var_dump(bin2hex($bytes));
```

> string(10) "385e33f741"

Answer (score 0):

you get the actual string but those character codes couldn't be displayed, depending on font you may see different count of them as 'normal' characters

if you want to see some letters you can follow some algorithm like this:
https://3v4l.org/FTQL5

```
$str = random_bytes(13);
$decoded = '';
$letterRange = (ord('a')-ord('Z'));
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++)
{
    $decoded .= chr(ord($str[$i])%$letterRange + ord('a'));
}
echo $str.'|'.$decoded;
```